# Visual Studio 2012 Text Visualizer Shortcut

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I'm using a the text visualizer for multiple strings which contain SQL queries.  It's frustrating when I mouse over a variable wait and then as I drag my mouse left towards the text visualizer icon (the magnification glass) it disappears.  If someone knows a keyboard shortcut, or even how to set one please clue me in.

Comment: Your user name is very appropriate.  Have you at least considered not putting a SQL query in "multiple strings"?

Comment: I'm using several Queries with temp tables and multiple steps. Just explaining why a shortcut would be useful to me.

Comment: Of cource having complex SQL inside the code is not very good thing, because of multiple reasons, including inability to debug SQL, no intellesense etc. Consider placing complex SQL where it belongs to, i.e. in Stored Procedures (whenever possible). To get Text Visualized, I'm usually press `Shift+F9` to get quick watch window and then click on the magnifying glass to see all the strings. Of course I would be happy to know one press solution instead. (so it's valid question, voting up)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Alt + DownArrow** works on VS2017 :)

Comment: Well hopefully this answer helps someone else. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In my understanding, as of now visual studio not providing any shortcut for TextVisualizer

Here is a useful VS2012 extension which you can clip inside a visual studio

http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/f2964c90-68e2-4ddd-861a-bd66e5cd4434